# JavaFX - button with hyperlink to another page

Tags: hyperlink, javafx-2, mouseclick-event, hbox

I want to make an application in JavaFX-2 based on two pages as "main" page and "extras" page. In the main page, I have added a Hbox function which includes a button named "extras". How do I define a second page and how can I set a hyperlink to the button (onMouseClicked event?), to refer to extras page? I could not find any examples on Mouse events related to this question. Thanks for help!

Comment: edit: extras page will not be a "pop-up". It should appear with a transition effect like sliding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [JFX Flow](http://www.zenjava.com/jfx-flow/) framework - it seems to have the functionality you are requesting, with back and forward navigation and transitions between scenes.

I created a [simple wizard implementation](https://gist.github.com/1887631) in response to a [forum post](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10370734) which helps perform some of this scene to scene style navigation.  I also created a small [sample of animating sliding panes](https://gist.github.com/1437374) of in and out of the screen which I also created earlier.  The code for the two concepts is not linked together, but the code is pretty simple so, it wouldn't be hard to link it.

There is a large source of [Canned animations](http://fxexperience.com/2012/03/canned-animations/) in the FXExperience project as well as plently of inbuilt [Transitions](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/basics.htm#CJAJJAGI) in JavaFX.